# Get text from textarea using Python & Selenium Webdriver (no value attribute)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I've looked and tried all i can, i'm in need of assistance. I'm trying to get the text from an element in a page. Its a popup but not an alert or a new window, just another popup within a frame. WebDriver appears to find the element, but when i run the print statement to check the text returned, it is consistently a blank line. I've tried, instead of get_attribute, .text as well... no luck.

Here's the html:

```
<textarea id="textareafield-2320-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-textarea" name="activityComments" rows="4" cols="20" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
```

Here's my code:

```
contents = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='x-form-item-input-row']/td[2]/textarea").get_attribute("value")
print contents
```

Comment: thanks for the update, this was my first question ever lol

Comment: You can use `find_element_by_id` instead of `xpath`. Did you try that?

Comment: the ids are being generated randomly so it changes all the time, same with the name.

Comment: why the down vote? just looking for some help after searching for days on this site and others. everyone says to use the value attribute, there isnt one. they say use the text, tried it. just looking for help. if youre gonna vote down, at least let me know why so i can improve my question

Comment: Are you sure, you're locating correct text area element??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `XPath` is quite broad. Several elements on page might be matched with this `XPath`. To check it try `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='x-form-item-input-row']/td[2]/textarea")))`. If result is more than `1`, you seem to handle wrong element.

Try to use more explicit `XPath`:

```
//textarea[starts-with(@id, "textareafield-")][@name="activityComments"]
```

Comment: welp, i'm embarassed... this worked! thanks so much, i need to work on my locator skills clearly. thanks again. i upvoted but since i just joined it wont display.

Comment: Also you might need to check this http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf